# How can I validate $value so it passes if a '0' is entered?

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if($value)
        $sorted[$parent_key][$newkey] = $value;
    else
        unset($_POST[$key]);
```

`$value` could be '0' or 'any string text.' How can I validate $value so it passes if a '0' is entered?

I cannot use `isset($value)` because the `$value` is set from the `foreach`.
I cannot use `empty($value)` because it treats the 0 as null.
I cannot use `strlen($value)` because it treats the 0 as null.
I cannot use `(!$value)` because it treats the 0 as null.

Comment: *"I cannot use strlen($value) because it treats the 0 as null."* What!? [`if (strlen($value) > 0)`](http://codepad.org/uYrzdCFV) should work.

Comment: @NullUserException was a problem elsewhere in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strlen($value) because it does not treat the 0 as null.
[here is the proof](http://codepad.org/nA2RfbdN)

```
$a = 0;
echo strlen($a);
```

Outputs:

```
1
```

Comment: I'm not exactly a fan of calling an int variable a `$str`

Comment: @NullUserException its just a varable name but you are right it should not be str i change it

Answer (score 1):

Simply by doing :

```
if($value || $value === "0")
```

Comment: @NullUserException I think my answer is legit

Comment: Before I downvote an answer - I usually comment and wait for a response - sometimes the answer is still being edited...

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($value) || (string)$value === '0')
        $sorted[$parent_key][$newkey] = $value;
    else
        unset($_POST[$key]);
```

Comment: I should have said `if(!empty($value)` is redundant compared to just `if($value`, because the symbol is guaranteed to be defined.

Comment: @rambocoder a good read: http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/